# How to handle difficult to meet requirements on freelancing projects

Tags: contracts, payment-terms, project-management, small-projects

I want to hire a freelancer to develop a machine learning algorithm. In order for the algorithm to provide any value I need it to work correct in over 95% of cases, which is a very difficult requirement to be met.

From my side, I cannot pay for something that works worse than that as it will have no value for me. And I fear people will not accept these hard requirements because any time and effort invested on their end might not produce the required results.

Is there a way I can mitigate this such as offering a very low rate for trying but not achieving the results? How should I handle this? Is there any best practice/strategy on requesting difficult RnD(research and development) requirements while minimizing my risk?

Comment: Please keep in mind it could be impossible to achieve such accuracy, not difficult or costly, but plain impossible. It could also be impossible to judge without a preliminary study and even then you could lose money. Your best bet (not from a freelancing point of view) would be to have a look at the literature or market and see if you find any similar application to your specific problem and gauge the results.

Comment: What is the success rate of a human on this task ? Does it even reach 95% ?

Answer (score 2):

> From my side, I cannot pay for something that works worse than that as it will have no value for me

Understandable. Viewed from the other end besides a student or an enthusiast you most likely won‘t find anybody …

A step back, ML is a filter, which depends on the history of its data offered. More generalized there‘s a lot of noise, so your are in the business of designing robust products. This can be done systematically, including identifying and improving limited concepts.

> Is there a way I can mitigate this such as offering a very low rate for trying but not achieving the results?

Consider your employer offers you just that … and you know the answer.

> Is there any best practice/strategy on requesting difficult RnD(research and development) requirements while minimizing my risk?

As I lined out above, evaluating and improving robustness of your system offers this. It won‘t be a one step process. Here are some things that will and have to happen on this path:

- You have a goal in mind and a couple of ideas or concept to achieve it
- That‘s a good starting point
- These concepts will demonstrate shortcomings (either by expensive market introduction with redesigns, or quick with robust …)
- Which means: your beloved idea will/has to die to make room for the more capable one
- Which will require at least one to-the-point invention
- Repeat
- While your system will perform so good, you can‘t believe it … if you dare taking this route.

To indicate roughly 2 out of 3 products have a hidden performance, which you simply can use afterwards. Roughly 1 out of 3 products „fail“ optimization attempts … and those are your gold mine. Why? Because their concept imposes limitations. How to overcome it on-the-fly? By said invention(s). Literally in hours. So you want to torture your ML to fail quickly, to invent, improve and learn fast … beyond books, conferences, working groups.

To sum it up, if you don‘t invest into a guide on this route, you won‘t get returns. If you do, you are on a turbo-learning-link, with a small team. Consider investing in this kind of know-how and capability, not into exchangeable capacity. Then review your risk concerns.

Best

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the simplest is to state the things as they are: you are looking for someone willing to accept the risk. He will tell you his/her rate for accepting the risk.

You can also suggest a smaller compensation in case of a failure. This is just a matter of finding someone foolish enough to accept. But if things are said upfront, nothing goes wrong.

---

Keep in mind that the risk is there and there is no reason that someone else should carry it for you.